# How to reference kubernetes secrets in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I want to make some deployments in kubernetes using helm charts. Here is a sample override-values yaml that I use:

```
imageRepository: ""

ocbb:
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    TZ: UTC
    logDir: /oms_logs
    tnsAdmin: /oms/ora_k8
    LOG_LEVEL: 3
    wallet:
        client: 
        server: 
        root:
    db:
        deployment:
            imageName: init_db
            imageTag:
        host: 192.168.88.80
        port:
        service:
        alias:
        schemauser: pincloud
        schemapass:
        schematablespace: pincloud
        indextablespace: pincloudx
        nls_lang: AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
        charset: AL32UTF8
        pipelineschemauser: ifwcloud
        pipelineschemapass:
        pipelineschematablespace: ifwcloud
        pipelineindextablespace: ifwcloudx
        pipelinealias:
        queuename:
```

In this file I have to set some values involving credentials, for example schemapass, pipelineschemapass...
Documentation states I have to generate kubernetes secrets to do this and add this key to my yaml file with the same path hierarchy.

I generated some kubernetes secrets, for example:

```
kubectl create secret generic schemapass --from-literal=password='pincloud'
```

Now I don't know how to reference this newly generated secret in my yaml file. Any tip about how to set schemapass field in yaml chart to reference kubernetes secret?

Comment: That's not the chart, it's just the `values.yaml` file that sets its initial parameters.  You should have some files that look like Kubernetes YAML files with some extra `{{ ... }}` markup in the `templates` directory, and one path is to create the Secret there instead of using `kubectl create`.  What Kubernetes object would need to reference the secret?

Comment: True, I was already editing post while you was writing your comment :)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want to include secret into helm values? Why not adding it into template which creates a pod?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot use Kubernetes secret in your `values.yaml`. In `values.yaml` you only specify the input parameters for the Helm Chart, so it could be the secret name, but not the secret itself (or anything that it resolved).

If you want to use the secret in your container, then you can insert it as an environment variable:

```
env:
- name: SECRET_VALUE_ENV
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: schemapass
      key: password
```

You can check more in the [Hazelcast Enterprise Helm Chart](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/tree/master/stable/hazelcast-enterprise). We do exactly that. You specify the secret name in `values.yaml` and then the secret is injected into the container using environment variable.

Comment: This sounds ideal, but I cannot find any reference to this in your values.yaml file linked. I have found an env: entry for MC_LICENSE_KEY in your other config files, but nothing in values.yaml.

Comment: yes, you cannot define it directly in `values.yaml`. In other words, if your templates are not prepared for this, you cannot inject secret just by specifying something in `values.yaml`.

Answer (score 5):

You can reference K8S values -whether secrets or not- in Helm by specifying them in your container as environment variables.

let your deployment be mongo.yml

```
--
kind: Deployment
   --
      --
      containers:
        --
        env:
        - name: DB_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config
              key: mongo-url
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
```

Where mongo-secret is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongo-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-user: bW9uZ291c2Vy
  mongo-password: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==
```

and mongo-config is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongo-config
data:
  mongo-url: mongo-service
```

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a [`lookup`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function, but it's fraught with [controversy](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8137) and can be tricky to debug

```
lookup apiVersion, kind, namespace, name -> resource or resource list
```

I have only managed to get it to work referencing secrets from the same chart (pointless); I ideally want to get at a value in a secret that I deploy through other means prior.

The application consumes a config file (it is what it is), which I am trying to curate on the fly via a helm template, have the entire file stored in the chart's secret, and volume-mount that within a deployment template.

I may well open a SO-post

---

##### UPDATE 2023/07/02: I have since discovered [External Secrets Operator](https://external-secrets.io/latest) (ESO)

###### What ESO Does For You

ESO nicely separates the concerns of input secrets and output secrets.

###### Input Secrets:

With its pluggable design you can source Secrets (and ConfigMaps) from Kubernetes (essentially internal secrets) or sensitive -data from AWS (e.g. Secrets Manager, Parameter Store) and other cloud providers (external secrets).

###### Output Secrets:

Based on input secrets you can either:

- Map them one-to-one into a Secret
- Map them many-to-one, using templating to generate a Secret e.g. containing a config file, where it safely inlines DB credentials

###### How You Can Use ESO

So with ESO, your Helm Chart's `values.yaml` is free to support a UX for those familiar with using Helm.

> **Pro-Tip**: Don't leak your *application's configuration structure* in to your `values.yaml`, thus tightly coupling the two; make use of the *'facade'* opportunity the latter presents you.

You can now define whatever notation you want, in your `values.yaml`, to indicate/reference a secret that should be used (and from where).

> **Idea**: A possible reference format could be:
> `secret://external-secret-store/external/secret/path/or/name#key-within-external-secret`
> This adopts a familiar URI-style, which predates Kubernetes/Helm, therefore should be fairly intuitive to your users out-of-the-box

Your `templates/*.yaml` can then interpret those references to generate:

1. ExternalSecrets, which in-turn inject and supervise Secrets, and
2. Deployments, for example, that reference those injected Secrets as volumes or environment-variables.

###### Example: A concrete application of this approach using the OP's (abbreviated) `values.yaml`:

```
imageRepository: ""

ocbb:
    ...
    db:
        ...
        schemauser: secret://my-parameter-store/ocbb/db/schema-credentials#username
        schemapass: secret://my-parameter-store/ocbb/db/schema-credentials#password
```

> **Insight**: The `values.yaml` has a structure of your choosing and you know `ocbb.db.schemapass`, etc, are credentials and may reference secrets, so you template accordingly.

- `my-parameter-store`: an ESO concept, setup to point to AWS Parameter Store
- `/ocbb/db/schema-credentials`: an AWS concept, the path to the parameter in AWS Parameter Store
- `username`,`password`: the keys in the JSON object i.e. the parameter in AWS Parameter Store

Comment: For the controvery on helm, they solved it. At least there is a way to test the variable using upgrade/install and `--dry-run=server` at the end.

Comment: example. `helm upgrade mychart . --install -f values.yaml -f values-overrride.cicd.yaml  --dry-run=server`