# helm chart : strings concatenation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

I am trying to concatenate variable in helmchart to develop connection strings.

connection string:

```
ConnectionStrings:TheSourceContext="Server=10.xx.xx.xx,1433;Database=Test;User Id=Test; Password=pass123;"
```

I am passing user id &password as secret but it is not working. it is not building up the requried strings.

```
      - name: DBUSERD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: dbuser
            name: api-catalogue
      - name: DBPASSD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            key: dbpass
            name: api-catalogue
      - name: ConnectionStrings__TheSourceContext
        value: {{ .Values.const.DBSVR }}{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsServer }},{{.Values.app.connectionStringsPort }}{{ .Values.const.DB }}{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsDB }}{{ .Values.const.DBUSR }}$(DBUSERD){{ .Values.const.DBPASS }}($DBPASSD)*
```

How to correct above variable so that it will work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447111/how-to-reference-kubernetes-secrets-in-helm-chart , see if this helps.

Comment: What doesn't work?  What output are you getting?  (`helm template` can show you the generated YAML without submitting it to Kubernetes.)  The sample string you show has some constant text and punctuation that your YAML doesn't obviously seem to (`Server=` for example).

Comment: Below Logic is working
 value: {{ .Values.const.DBSVR }}{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsServer }},{{.Values.app.connectionStringsPort }}{{ .Values.const.DB }}{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsDB }}{{ .Values.const.DBUSR }}{{ printf $ }}{{ .Values.const.DBPASS }}{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsPassword }}

Below entry in values.yaml
const:
  DBSVR:  "Server="
  DB: ";Database="
  DBUSR:  ";User ID="
  DBPASS: "; Password="
---------------------------
Issue is when I use secrets as variable & try to use those variable it is throwing error
 As shared in first post

Comment: With
value: {{ .Values.const.DBSVR }} {{ .Values.app.connectionStringsServer }},{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsPort }}{{ .Values.const.DB }}{{ .Values.app.connectionStringsDB }} {{ .Values.const.DBUSR }} {{ printf "%s:$DBUSERD" }}{{ .Values.const.DBPASS }}{{ printf "%s:$DBPASSD" }}


Output:
ConnectionStrings__TheSourceContext = "Server= 10.241.64.28,1433;Database=TheSource_new ;User ID= %!s(MISSING):$DBUSERD; Password=%!s(MISSING):$DBPASSD"Password=%!s(MISSING):$DBPASSD

Comment: Can you update this into the question? Please avoid placing code or commands in the comments.

Comment: @rahul131286, any progress with this issue ? Did you manage to solve it ?