# Get secret for the Helm Chart from GCP Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, google-secret-manager, gcp-secret-manager

Is there any way to retrieve secrets for the Helm Chart from the GCP Secret Manager during the chart deployment CI/CD pipeline? Or is better to use CI/CD secret manager and then there pull credentials for the chart deployment?

Answer (score 2):

There are some information regarding using Google Secret Manager in GKE and best practices in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/using-other-products#google-kubernetes-engine).
You should be able to use it like mentioned [here](https://blog.doit-intl.com/kubernetes-and-secrets-management-in-cloud-858533c20dca) or you can also try plugin like [helm-secrets](https://github.com/jkroepke/helm-secrets).
There's similar questions with answers that could be helpful [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447111/how-to-reference-kubernetes-secrets-in-helm-chart).

Comment: Secrets Store CSI driver looks promising but it is not supported way and code state is not stable. `secrets-init` looks minimalistic and easy to use but is going to work on docker images which you own nothing pulled from the docker hub. On another hand `helm-secret` may do the job for such of images but example for GCP is not clear.

Comment: Just got an info on `helm-secrets` project that they are still working on GCP Secret Manager implementation so currently I'm limited to the `secrets-init`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to read secrets from GCP secrets.

1. Install helm secrets Plugin by running the following command.

   helm plugin install https://github.com/jkroepke/helm-secrets --version v4.4.1
2. Install [vals](https://github.com/helmfile/vals)
3. Make sure the user on your workstation or CI/CD automation (service Account) tool has access to read google secrets from the project.
4. Update your parameters in value.yaml as for following example.

   mysqlpassword: ref+gcpsecrets://my-gcp-project/mysql-password
5. Run the following command to apply the changes.

   helm secrets --evaluate-templates upgrade --install chart-name . --namespace=custom-namespace -f values.yaml